# OpenLink Virtuoso - Uploading RDF file into a named graph via HTTP API

Tags: virtuoso

Relevant docs: http://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/dataspace/doc/dav/wiki/Main/VirtRDFInsert

I'm trying to upload an RDF file in Turtle format into Virtuoso with a named graph.

With Sesame/Fuseki/4Store this is a simple API call, but I gather from the docs that I have to upload the file into a user's DAV folder. I managed to do this by making a HTTP PUT request to `/DAV/home/{user}/rdf_sink/{randomlygeneratedfilename}.ttl`, however I can't seem to specify the name of the graph to upload the data into. 
Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HTTP PUT with the `sparql-graph-crud-auth` URL works, and has a `graph-uri` query parameter: http://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/dataspace/doc/dav/wiki/Main/VirtGraphProtocolCURLExamples